# read excel file in the dasboard programmatically

Tags: dashboard

To read a excel file inside wordpress, is there any function available, or we should build all using php?

Comment: There’s nothing built into WordPress. You need to code it yourself or use a library.

Comment: thanks, already trying to use fopen and fgetcsv, or I will have to use a library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To read a excel file inside wordpress, is there any function available

WordPress does not provide functions for reading spreadsheets. PHP provides functions for reading CSV files via `fgetcsv` etc, but these are for `.csv` files.

If you want to open an `xls` or `xlsx` file in code, and read its contents, you will need to find a PHP library for this, or implement the code yourself. A quick search of libraries on packagist reveals multiple pages of results for the word "excel".

Keep in mind that what you are asking if not a WordPress question, but a generic PHP question, you don't have to limit yourself to just WordPress to solve this.